# Good XeTeX Books

Tags: xetex, books

I'm looking for some good books on XeTeX to have them as references whenever I want to look up something or learn something new. Level doesn't really matter, either novice or advanced would do but I'd really like the book(s) to be broad in content - like some of the LaTeX books that I've read:

*A Guide to LaTeX* by H. Kopka and P. Daly

*The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2ε* by T. Oetiker

Many thanks for any recommendations,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XeTeX is in opposite to ConTeXt just another compiler engine (like PDFTeX) and not a separate typesetting system. So it can't do any harm to read LaTeX documentation. A kind of XeTeX documentation is given with the manuals of some specific packages.

- [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)
- [mathspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec)
- [polyglossia](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia)
- [xltxtra](http://ctan.org/pkg/xltxtra)
- [xunicode](http://ctan.org/pkg/xunicode)

I'm sure you will find much more useful information on the [XeTeX Project Homepage](http://xetex.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

1. Many books about LaTeX in general are mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex/).
2. Documentation about XeTeX can be found [here](http://www.tug.org/xetex/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in XeLaTex *and* read French, you may find this book useful: [**Maïeul Rouquette**, (Xe)LaTeX appliqué aux sciences humaines, 2012](http://geekographie.maieul.net/95). The code is open source.

Comment: As author of this book, I could let know that it contain very little specific thing about XeTeX. It is more on XeLaTeX than on XeTeX. The only point for XeLaTeX are the use of `fontspec` and `polyglossia` package.

Comment: Ah, true, I assumed XeLaTex would also be of interest! Great book btw.