# Is there any textbook for XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, documentation, books

I usually use PdfTeX. Currently I have to learn XeLaTeX which I am not familiar with. So

1. Is there any textbook for XeLaTeX?
2. How to use numerous math fonts in one article?

E.g. use mathrsfs, yfonts, amsmath, dsfont, amssymb, mnsymbol, mathabx together.

It is the primary problem I am facing.

1. How to use `\fam`?

Comment: Do you already know the documents in `doc/xetex` & `doc/xelatex` and hence search for other information?

Comment: @Speravir Well, they have many notes, and I don't know which is suitable.

Comment: Those were 2 questions. Please keep questions separate, so the answers don't turn out tangled.

Comment: for the first question on textbook for XeLaTeX refer [Good XeTeX Books](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5715/15717)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the `\fam` or the various font packages; if you use XeLaTeX, you can use the package [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) to use Unicode math fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math,fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
Foo bar
\[
  \mathscr{A}+\mathbb{B}=\mathfrak{C}
\]
Baz
\end{document}
```